# Error when attempting to run PubSub emulator locally

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to do some pubsub testing locally so I have done "gcloud components install pubsub-emulator".

Now when I attempt to do "gcloud beta emulators pubsub start" I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.pubsub.start) [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

I am using Java version 1.8. Using Java9 wasn't working for me, and someone recommended I downgrade. I can't find any mention of this error. My .profile looks like this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/develop/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```

My .bashrc looks like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When I type java -version I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is not related to your Java environment, as you are running a JRE version supported by Google Cloud PubSub Emulator. So in that case, I would recommend you to first check whether you have the latest version of the emulator:

```
gcloud components update
```

Then, try running the emulator with the *--host-port* flag, for example:

```
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --host-port=<hostname>:<port>
```

*Hostname* can be localhost in your case and *port* any available port you have, 8085 as an example.

If none of that works, consider restarting your connection, as it looks like that workaround solved some similar issues with the ***[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known*** error.

Comment: embarrassingly enough, resetting my network was the trick. Now, I'm stuck trying to create a topic. It is saying I am not authorized. Do I need to create some kind of local project and local organization to get this to work?

Comment: I'd recommend you to make a new question if you are facing problems unrelated to this one, following the policies of Stack Overflow. However, I would recommend you to check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access_control).

Comment: The flag should be `--host-port=`, not `--host-port:`.